# How does it feel to you? vs How do you feel about it?

Tags: word-usage

Do

> How does it feel to you?

and

> How do you feel about it?

imply the same feelings?

Comment: Can you give example sentences? The answer to this question is more semantic and it will depend on the context. For example, the first might be considered less personal and direct while the second is more personal and direct. However, in some cases the first one can be quite intimate.

Answer (score 3):

I would say they are not the same, but the difference is subtle.
"How does it feel to you" asks for a sensory perception of "it." 
"How do you feel about it" inquires as to the listener's emotions.

So... your choice depends on whether you wish to ask about the object, or about the person.

Comment: I'd agree to a great extent. At the extremes of the definition you are definitely right: discussing the feel of a fabric, for instance you would say "How does it feel to you?" but discussing a proposed change in your office hierarchy you would say "How do you feel about it?". However there is an overlap where either term may be applicable. For example discussing the ambiance of a restaurant or the attractiveness of a prospective home, workspace or even car either form of words might be used.